# Difficult limit question involving Euler's number and L'Hospital

Tags: limits, indeterminate-forms, eulers-number-e

The limit I'm trying to evaluate is
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty} e^x \left[e - \left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^x\right]
$$

After some hours trying, I've made almost no progress. I always end up in some indeterminate form and L'Hospital isn't getting me anywhere (though I think that, if used properly, it might solve the problem). Maybe it's not even that difficult and I'm just stuck for some stupid reason. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using the fact that limits are distributive over addition and multiplication? (Assuming the two limits exist).

Comment: I think the limit must be infinity. The reason: the function $\;\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x\;$ is monotonic increasing and at $\;\infty\;$ the limit is $\;e\;$ . Than means the expression within the parentheses is always positive. 

We also know that $\;\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}e\;$ rather slowly (and at any rate much slower than the taylor series converges to $\;e\;$ when $\;x=1\;$, thus the exponential outside the parentheses, which diverges to infinity, will overcome the expression inside the parentheses which converges to zero. This is not a proof but...

Comment: @DonAntonio I must confess to you I haven't studied Taylor Series yet, neither the professsor taught the subject to us, so yeah, your intuition is correct (wolfram alpha says that the limit is indeed infinity), but I don't know how to show it. But thanks a lot for your idea, it makes a lot of sense!!!

Comment: @S34NM68 I've tried that already, but that hasn't taken me very far :/

Comment: This is not a proof and I don't have time to write one right now, but it seems like we have the indeterminate form $\infty \cdot 0$, so that should tell us we have to write $e^x = \frac{1}{e^{-x}}$ and do L'Hôpital's Rule. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: @S34NM68 Distributing the limit wouldn't work because the limit as $x \to \infty$ of $e^x$ isn't finite.

Answer (score 4):

We want to know how quickly the term in the square bracket goes to $0$. The usual proof used to show that it converges towards $0$ needs order $1$ Taylor expansion of the logarithm but here we need a slighly more sophisticated approximation thus we will need to do a second order expansion of the logarithm.

\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x} &= e^{x \ln(1+\frac{1}{x})}\\
&= e^{x (\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{2 x^2} + o(\frac{1}{x^2}))} \text{ using } \log(1+u) = u-\frac{u^{2}}{2} + o(u^2)(u \rightarrow 0)\\
&=  e^{1 - \frac{1}{2x} + o(\frac{1}{x}))}\\
&= e e^{\frac{-1}{2x} + o(\frac{1}{x})} \\ 
&= e (1 - \frac{1}{2x} + o(\frac{1}{x})) \text{ using } e^u=1+u+o(u)(u \rightarrow 0)\\
&= e-\frac{e}{2x}+o(\frac{1}{x})(x \rightarrow +\infty) 
\end{align}
thus
$$ e-\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x}\sim_{+\infty} \frac{e}{2x}$$

This connects to many posts that pointed out it seems to behave like $\frac{C}{x}$ with a certain constant $C$, which is in fact $C=\frac{e}{2}$.

We can then do the product of the two equivalents :

$$
e^{x}\left[e-\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x}\right] \sim_{+\infty} e^x\frac{e}{2x}
$$
By elementary calculus, we know that $\frac{e^x}{x}$ goes towards infinity when $x$ goes to infinity, therefore the total expression goes towards $+\infty$ since $C >0$.

I suppose just using l'Hopital's rule (which I do not like because it justs make things "magic" while it should be elementary and understandable) fails here because you need information about the second order expansion somewhere, while l'Hopitals rule is just a fancy name for a first order expansion.

Answer (score 3):

You can at least guess what the answer should be by computing $f(x) = e - \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)^x$ for some large values of $x$ and seeing how it behaves. For example, [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=e+-+%281+%2B+1%2F100%29%5E100) will tell you that

$$f(10) = 0.125 \dots $$
$$f(100) = 0.0135 \dots $$
$$f(1000) = 0.00137 \dots $$

which suggests that we have $f(x) \sim \frac{C}{x}$ for some constant $C$, in which case the desired limit is $\infty$; $e^x$ grows much faster than $f(x)$ decays. It's actually quite overkill; the limit would still be $\infty$ if we replaced $e^x$ with $x^{1 + \varepsilon}$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$.

There are a couple of different ways to finish the argument from here. The lowest-tech version is probably to restrict to the case that $x$ is a positive integer $n$, then use the binomial theorem to expand

$$\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} \frac{1}{n^k} = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \left( 1 - \frac{i}{n} \right).$$

Since $e = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}$ and each term of this series is greater than or equal to the corresponding term of the above series, this gives

$$e - \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n \ge \frac{1}{2n}$$

(considering the difference between the $k = 2$ terms only). Since, as Don says in the comments, $\left( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)^x$ is monotonically increasing, this implies a similar bound for all positive real $x$ (alternatively, we can apply the generalized binomial theorem for non-integer exponents), and we're done.

Alternatively, we can argue by writing

$$\ln \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)^x = x \ln \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \right) \le x \left( \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{2x^2} + \frac{1}{3x^3} \right)$$

which gives

$$\left( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)^x \le \exp \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2x} + \frac{1}{3x^2} \right)$$

and hence

$$e - \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)^x \ge e \left( 1 - \exp \left( - \frac{1}{2x} + \frac{1}{3x^2} \right) \right)$$

which again is enough to conclude, using for example the inequality $\exp x \le 1 + (e-1)x$ for $x \in [0, 1]$.

> **Follow-up exercise:** Evaluate $\lim_{x \to \infty} x \left( e - \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)^x \right)$. (This one isn't $\infty$!)

Answer (score 2):

In every analysis book there should be a proof of the limit
$$
  \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n = e\;,
$$
which will usually take these steps:

1. show that the sequence $e_n = (1 + 1/n)^n$ is increasing;
2. show that the sequence $e_n^* = (1 + 1/n)^{n+1}$ is decreasing;
3. $e_n$ converges, since $e_n < e_n^* < e_1^* = 4$.

The number $e$ is normally defined to be $\lim_{n\to\infty} e_n$, but
we also have $e_n^* \to e$, since
$$
  0 < e_n^* - e_n = \frac{e_n^*}{n + 1} < \frac{e_1^*}{n + 1} \to 0
$$
This difference, in fact, gives an error bound for the convergence of
$e_n \to e$:
$$
  E_n = e - e_n < \frac{4}{n+1}
$$

Now, this result is for a sequence but it should be possible to extend
it to a function of real variable. So, for your limit we can say:
$$
 e^x \left[e - \left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^x\right] 
 \asymp \frac{e^x}{x} \to \infty.
$$

---

Note: by $f(x) \asymp g(x)$ I mean there are constants $x_0,a,b>0$ such
that $a < |f(x)/g(x)| < b\;\; \forall x>x_0$.

Comment: This is my favourite answer so far, because it can be found by carefully following a trail of ideas — no step requires any inspiration or spotting a distant connection.  The first naïve things you try show that you need to think about “how quickly does $e - (1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ go to $0$?”; this points you to look carefully at some proof(s) that $\lim (1+\frac{1}{n})^n = e$; and then extracting the error bounds used in those proofs gives this argument.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e-(1+\frac1x)^x}{e^{-x}}\\=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e-e^{x\ln(1+\frac1x)}}{e^{-x}}$$

Applying L'Hopital,

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-e^{x\ln(1+\frac1x)}\left(\frac{x}{1+\frac1x}(-\frac1{x^2})+\ln(1+\frac1x)\right)}{-e^{-x}}\\=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(1+\frac1x)^x\left(-\frac1{x+1}+\ln(1+\frac1x)\right)}{e^{-x}}$$

Now, $\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+\frac1x)^x=e$, and on the rest, re-applying L'Hopital,

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e\left(\frac1{(x+1)^2}+\frac1{1+\frac1x}(-\frac1{x^2})\right)}{-e^{-x}}\\=\lim_{x\to\infty}-e^{x+1}\left(\frac1{(x+1)^2}-\frac1{x+1}\right)\\=\lim_{x\to\infty}-e^{x+1}\left(\frac{1-x-1}{(x+1)^2}\right)\\=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{xe^{x+1}}{(x+1)^2}$$

Applying L'Hopital,

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{xe^{x+1}+e^{x+1}}{2(x+1)}\\=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^{x+1}}2=\infty$$